# Generate Liferay Web Service with Document/Literal format

Tags: web-services, soap, liferay

I have to generate a client for a Liferay web service. But this client only accepts Document/Literal web services.

When I generate a WS with Liferay, it is created as RPC/Encoded, as you can see in the next code:

```
<wsdlsoap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
```

Is it possible to generate the WS with Document/Literal format?

Thanks.

Comment: see also: https://www.liferay.com/en_GB/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/62048766

Comment: That is the same thread I left in Liferay's forum